# Get Task Definition Name for ECS Task Definition

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am running into an issue where I am trying to run the following command:

```
aws ecs list-task-definitions | grep Foo-Task-Testing | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'
```

This returns exactly what I am looking for which is just the task definition name.

When running the command in the CLI with just grep i get this:

```
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:task-definition/Foo-Task-Testing-TaskDefinition-OYBZ78KBUI57:1",
```

When including Awk, I get:

`Foo-Task-Testing-TaskDefinition-OYBZ78KBUI57:1"`

However, when I try to add this to my Jenkins pipeline:

```
ecsTaskDefinitionName = Foo-Task-Testing
ecsTaskDefinition = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws ecs list-task-definitions | grep $ecsTaskDefinitionName | awk -F '/' '{print \$2}'").trim()
```

I always get this error message:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/foo_test_PR-828@tmp/durable-a5ce4670/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/foo_test_PR-828@tmp/durable-a5ce4670/script.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I have a feeling this has to do with how I am using Awk in Groovy but I can't seem to find enough examples online to confirm this. Can anyone either provide a way of doing this in Groovy w/o using Awk or any experienced Groovy programmers can tell me the correct way of passing Awk?

Comment: Can you provide the intermediate outputs that each pipe produces? e.g., what does `list-task-definitions` output, what does the `grep` output, and what does the `awk` output?

Comment: also why is the `\$2` escaped in the jenkins pipeline version? (`'{print \$2}'`)

Comment: I have to escape the `$` otherwise Jenkins will complain about it

Comment: can you avoid the need for `awk` with `grep -o`? `... | grep -o Foo-Task-Testing.*` returns `Foo-Task-Testing-TaskDefinition-OYBZ78KBUI57:1` (`-o` only returns the match, `.*` greedily matches everything)

Comment: or in groovy perhaps `ecsTaskDefinitions = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws ecs list-task-definitions").trim();
ecsTaskDefinitionName = "Foo-Task-Testing";
ecsTaskDefinition = ecsTaskDefinitions.find(/${ecsTaskDefinitionName}.*$/)`

Comment: @thehole `grep -o` seemed to have worked. Please add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the need for `awk` with `grep -o`:

```sh
... | grep -o Foo-Task-Testing.*
```

returns

`Foo-Task-Testing-TaskDefinition-OYBZ78KBUI57:1`

(-o only returns the match, .* greedily matches everything after)